# Is there any limit of Handler creation in an activity android?

Tags: android, android-handler, android-thread

We can create Handler in an activity as many as we want using `new Handler()` and then use those handler to post and remove Runnable anonymous classes. We can also use HandlerThread in an activity for handling task in another thread. But how much Handler actually we can create in an activity android.

My question, is there any limit of creation Handler or any standard guideline about Handler creation in an specific activity. Any descriptive answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Question is why you need multiple Handlers ? For two HandlerThread you need only two Handlers to comunucate between them ... [fx you have one HandlerThread and UI thread ... you need to handlers to comunications](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/eaf75cf244df4d2f2ee6)

Comment: @Selvin For separation of my all Runnable classes using different handler if I have lots of Runnable in an activity and want to manage them using multiple Handler.

Comment: You might have million `Runnable`s and just one `Handler`, no need to create million `Handler`s.

Comment: @azizbekian Doesn't it impact on UI thread performance or efficiency to create multiple Runnable and handle it using single Handler?

Comment: Sure it does. Depends what use case you have. Why exactly you need to `post` on a `handler` instead of directly running the code from `Runnable`?

Comment: Because, I have lots of asynchronous task running and UI update related stuffs.

Comment: https://medium.com/@frank.tan/using-a-thread-pool-in-android-e3c88f59d07f